# Get the data from multiple datasources irrepective of data available in primary datasource

Tags: tableau-api

I have one database with 2 months of data (e.g Jan and Feb) and other database has 12 months of data (Jan to Dec).

My task is to show only the data from both databases but for only months in primary database, in the sense my report should have data only for Jan and Feb as only 2 months exists in primary database

**What I have tried:**

As option1 tried to blend the data but problem is for some Id's their is no data for Jan, so in this case data from secondary database also not showing since their is no data in primary database.

Second option I tried to link databases and take left join on ID, and used `Fixed` LoD to pick full data,now I got data but problem here is if I used the date field from secondary database then I am getting `0 (though my data is 1000)` if I take datefield from primary database then I get data for full year since I used `Fixed LoD`

How can I get data for only those months from secondary database (irrespective of primary database has data for those months)?

Comment: You don't want to be `joining` the two datasets: you should try `unioning` them.

Comment: @matt_black thanks for the reply, can you please explain use of union instead of joining?

Comment: If the data structure of two databases is the same but the time period covered is different, then `joining` won't even work (there won't be any common data fields). `Union` combines two similar tables into a single table with the same common structure, which is what you seem to want to do. In Tableau you can union two different tables at the point of connecting to the data source.